# Multiple Show/Hides with same class

Tags: jquery, class, hide, show

I have multiple UL's with the same class that cannot be changed to individual classes. I'm looking to have only the clicked show/hide expand when clicked instead of all the ul's expanding. I'm hiding the content after the third Li. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Code Below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("ul.gigpress-listing").find("li:gt(2)").hide();

$("ul.gigpress-listing").has("li:nth-child(3)").after("<span class=\"showhide_tours\">+     Show More</span><br/><br/>");

$("span.showhide_tours").click(function() {
$("ul.gigpress-listing").find("li:gt(3)").slideToggle("fast");

});

});;
```

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you're wanting without looking at your markup, but i'm assuming you want something along the lines of.

```
  $("span.showhide_tours").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').find("li:gt(3)").slideToggle("fast");
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately that did not work. For some reason when using (this) the show function does not work. Any other ideas? I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding a `span` after every `ul` which has more than 3 li's you can try this.

```
$("span.showhide_tours").click(function() {
   $(this).prev()//This will get the previous ul element
   .find("li:gt(3)").slideToggle("fast");
});
```